# Onyx Boox Max 3 - how save a web page as a pdf (chrome, default)

Tags: chrome-for-android, share-menu, printing

My Onyx Boox Max 3 ebook reader uses Android 9. There is no print option from the share menu though. I've installed a couple of web to pdf apps and can't get those to work either.  Any ideas?

Comment: btw, if anyone with a higher rating can create a boox tag I think that would be more appropriate than android

Comment: Don't you see "chrome print" in share menu? This change is discussed here https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14151904?hl=en

Comment: @beeshyams no, it is not in the list.  I think it is something custom about the Onyx Boox setup

Comment: lobo? I'm not sure what you mean there

Comment: Ah ok! Onyx Boox is a device, it runs Android, the share option isn't available in Chrome.  I'm guessing there is a print functionality somewhere built into android that has been disabled?